# How to Update values in sql by Muliple Column name in Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want add values to multiple columns

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DynamicInsertQuery 
    @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @RiD VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DynamicQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @DynamicQuery = 'UPDATE tbl_route_info SET ('+ @ColumnName +') = (1) WHERE RouteId=('+@RiD+')'

    EXEC(@DynamicQuery)
END
```

This is the code I tried.

I run this procedure like this

```
DynamicInsertQuery '(1,2)','10'
```

Comment: You will need a split function to extract the column names. This is also getting close to SQL injection, be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DynamicInsertQuery (
     @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX),
     @RiD VARCHAR(50)
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DynamicQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @DynamicQuery = 'update tbl_route_into set @ColumnName = 1 where RouteId = @RiD';
    SET @DynamicQuery = REPLACE(@DynamicQuery, '@ColumnName', @ColumnName);

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery, N'@RiD VARCHAR(50)', @RiD = @RiD;
END;
```

Notes:

- You have too many parentheses in your version.
- If you are learning to use dynamic SQL, then learn `sp_executesql` -- and how to use it to pass parameters.
- You cannot pass names of things (columns, tables, etc.) as parameters, so that has to be placed directly in the string.
- You can pass values into the string, such as `@RiD`.

Comment: Thanks.But i want Multiple Column names like below

Comment: sp_execSql (1,2,3),'20'    Here 1,2,3 are column names   that means 1 is column name 2 is column name 3 i s column name